# Fixed position in only one direction

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

So, essentially, I'd like to have an item that is fixed to the the bottom of the page, but when the view scrolls horizontally, it should horizontally scroll too.

I can hack out a means of doing this with JavaScript, but is there any CSS way to do it? I don't mind a few extra DIVs here and there.

Comment: Isn't that what fixed positioning does? Or did you mean when you move horizontally, it should **not** horizontally scroll

Comment: are you talking about floating footer , what about horizontal scrool , see if this question is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146659/how-do-i-get-a-floating-footer-to-stick-to-the-bottom-of-the-viewport-in-ie-6

Comment: No. With fixed positioning, the maximum width of the `div` or w/e is the width of the browser window, as far as I can tell.

Comment: **CSS only solution**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887834/css-position-fixed-div-wrapper-must-be-fixed-vertically-but-must-be-varying-in/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CSS part:

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px
}
```

jQuery part:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#footer').css('left','-'+$(window).scrollLeft()+'px');
});
```

Comment: I don't think assigning a negative left value will do exactly what was asked.

Answer (score 2):

Really the jQuery part must be like:

```
var s = $(window).scrollLeft() - scroll_old;    
scroll_old = $(window).scrollLeft(); // initially = 0;
var diff = left_num - s;
var new_left = diff+"px";
```

then like above...