# fixed left column vertically, but scrollable horizontally

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

in a web page there is three columns, left, middle and right;
within three columns only **left column is position:fixed** and others are normal.

while vertical scrolling, left column should remain fixed while others are scrolling.

but when browser size is reduced; while horizontal scrolling the all three columns should scrollable horizontally not only middle and right.

how to overcome this problem ? with **pure css** (without using js or jquery)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887834/css-position-fixed-div-wrapper-must-be-fixed-vertically-but-must-be-varying-in this may help you. Footer solution with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There has already been a similar question to this and a jQuery solution was provided. Have a look at it here to see if the answers provided help you:- [How do I get a fixed position div to scroll horizontally with the content? Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676131/how-do-i-get-a-fixed-position-div-to-scroll-horizontally-with-the-content-using)

Comment: any way without doing it with, jquery or javascript ? and with pure css ?

Comment: I don't think so no. That's the nature of using `position: fixed` - it will be fixed in position, whether you scroll horizontally or vertically. The simplest way to override its position as you scroll horizontally would be to use a jQuery solution.