# How to make a DIV always float on the screen in top right corner?

Tags: javascript, css

How do I make a DIV always float on the screen's top right corner, so that even when I scroll the page down, the DIV still shows up in the same fixed location? Thanks.

Comment: see this link , i think you want the opposite of sticky floating footer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146659/how-do-i-get-a-floating-footer-to-stick-to-the-bottom-of-the-viewport-in-ie-6

Answer (score 90):

Use `position: fixed`, and anchor it to the `top` and `right` sides of the page:

```
#fixed-div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

IE6 does not support `position: fixed`, however. If you need this functionality in IE6, [this purely-CSS solution](http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6) seems to do the trick. You'll need a wrapper `<div>` to contain some of the styles for it to work, as seen in the [stylesheet](http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/layout.css).

Comment: Thanks, but I need a cross-browser solution, whether or not it involves only CSS or a mix of CSS and Javascript.

Comment: To comment on the position:fixed not working in IE, http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html is the workaround for this.

Comment: @akavsky are you ok with jquery function $(window).scroll(function () {
       
    }); then we can easily postion that at the ....right corner using jquerys animate

Comment: While answering a different question I managed to figure out why the solution I link to seems to work. If you're curious to know the details, they're all here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718319/why-does-overflow-x-hidden-make-my-absolutely-positioned-element-become-fixed/14740580#14740580

Comment: Still works great! In 2022, I'm very happy to have no concern about whether or not IE6 is supported! :D

Answer (score 12):

Use `position:fixed`, as previously stated, IE6 doesn't recognize `position:fixed`, but with some css magic you can get IE6 to behave:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
body #fixedElement {
    position:fixed !important;
    position: absolute; /*ie6 */
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The `!important` flag makes it so you don't have to use a conditional comment for IE. This will have `#fixedElement` use `position:fixed` in all browsers but IE, and in `IE`, `position:absolute` will take effect with `bottom:0`. This will simulate `position:fixed` for IE6

Comment: You can also use `* html body #fixedElement { position: absolute; }` after that rule.

Comment: Did this in Chrome, but the 2nd position overwires the 'fixed', so I would swap the order of those two. That will make this work

Comment: @patrick: It shouldn't if you added the `!important` flag correctly. That said, of course swapping both works as well, without the need for `!important`.