# CSS3: Make next item indent more

Tags: css

I'm wondering if there's a way to add extra `margin-left` to each next item, such as

```
-Item1
  -Item2
    -Item3
      -and so forth
```

Is this possible with CSS3? I haven't seen anything for 'every next item'.

Comment: Does "next item" refer to "next sibling"?

Comment: Yes. In this case they are `<li>` items.

Comment: Silly question: why on earth would you want to do this? Indentation implies that the next element is part of a sub-list, not a sibling.

Comment: It's not silly. It's for visual reasons.

Comment: I second what @Blazemonger has to say

Comment: If you saw the design you would understand. I'm just looking for a simple CSS way to do this without IDing each one or using JS.

Comment: this is true, in fact what you have drawn is <ul><li>...<ul><li>...</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: You're trying to do something very non-standard, so you'll have to come up with a non-standard solution and indent each element explicitly. Sorry, there's no easy way to implement what you want.

Comment: That is the way it is to appear, not actually be in the mark up. This question can be used for more than just list items. It's just for visual reasons people.. the image is a star, not a disc or numeral. Large text. Graphic reasons, just don't want messy markup.

Comment: Default ul>li>ul>li>ul>li etc. looks like you want: http://jsfiddle.net/5XpXv/

Comment: I second what @kcdwayne says. I want to do precisely the same thing; and saying 'you don't want to do that' really doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can. But it's freaky ...

Demo : http://jsbin.com/exuwej/1/edit

CSS :

```
ul {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    list-style: none;
    height: 400px;
}

ul li {
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: -1 for only specifying WebKit prefixes without including unprefixed transforms, much less a notice about other vendor prefixes. Transforms are a standard, and not a WebKit-only thing.

Comment: I can't argue with you :) You're one of my favourite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718319/why-does-overflow-x-hidden-make-my-absolutely-positioned-element-become-fixed

Comment: I've removed my downvote. And no worries, I downvoted only because I'm strict when it comes to vendor prefix issues.

Comment: You are right about that. Sometimes I'm in a hurry to answer and forget about all those prefixes, but it's never good for novice.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this indefinitely, without javascript, but you ***could*** write a handful of CSS selectors for it. Though I would advise against doing this for reasons already stated by others.

```
li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
li+li {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
li+li+li {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
li+li+li+li {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I guess that works. More simple than javascript or IDing. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer this to the other one, primarily because the other one only works for certain heights/widths and requires quite a bit of angle tweeking to get it outside the sweet-zone posted.

Comment: Ooh, I like this. It's still evil and horrible, of course, but it's simple and gets the job done nicely.