# Can a position:absolute element be made sticky?

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

In CSS, `position: sticky` enables an element to display with a `position: static` behaviour (ie. it adopts its default position within the document flow) until it reaches a certain scroll position, after which it adopts `position: fixed` behaviour.

So... does that mean we cannot use `position: sticky` on an element which requires a normal behaviour of `position: absolute`?

---

**Context:**

I have an out-of-flow element which occupies a position towards the top-left corner of the viewport. After an inch or two of scrolling, the element hits the top of the viewport and, ideally, I'd like it not to carry on disappearing at that point.

Comment: Unfortunately it only supports relative positioning. Also note that `position: sticky` currently has [**no support**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) in Internet Explorer, and spotty support for the other browsers. I'd recommend against it personally.

Comment: Please note, in CSS the default value of `position` is `static` and not `relative`.

Comment: Yes, of course it is. Question updated to acknowledge this.

Answer (score 6):

You actually can leverage `display: grid` and have a sticky element that doesn't pushes its siblings:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px dashed #f00;
}

main {
  display: grid;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section {
  grid-column: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px dashed #0f0;
}

.first.section {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.sticky {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 1px dashed #0ff;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px dashed #f00;
}
```

```html
<header>I'm the header</header>
<main>
  <div class="sticky">I'm sticky</div>
  <div class="first section">Just</div>
  <div class="section">some</div>
  <div class="section">sections</div>
</main>
<footer>I'm the footer</footer>
```

The trick here is to place the sticky section **and** its first sibling on the first row and first column of their parent (because grids allow us to place many elements in the same cell).

The sticky element remains sticky in its parent so it will stay on scroll beyond its cell.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, as the `sitcky` div is not positioned absolutely in the container (out of flow).

Answer (score 2):

As GibboK says, the default positioning scheme isn't absolute positioning, it's the static position. Elements are laid out in normal flow by default — if out-of-flow were the default, then the default HTML page would be impossible to read. Besides, absolutely positioned elements do scroll with the page most of the time — the *only* time you can make an absolutely positioned behave like a fixed positioned element with respect to page scrolling is [through some semi-complicated CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718319/why-does-overflow-x-hidden-make-my-absolutely-positioned-element-become-fixed/14740580#14740580).

If you're asking whether it's possible for

- a stickily positioned element to be out-of-flow when stuck and unstuck, or
- for the containing block of a stickily positioned element to be determined the same way as for an absolutely positioned element,

then unfortunately neither of these is supported by sticky positioning.

Comment: Yes, I worded the question badly. I have an out-of-flow element which occupies a position towards the top-left corner of the viewport. After an inch or two of scrolling, the element hits the top of the viewport and, ideally, I'd like it not to carry on disappearing at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `position:sticky` is that it is only `fixed` while the parent element is not in view. A `position:absolute` element isn't attached to it's parent.

It could be interesting if such a `position` would exist and the rule would be that the element would be `absolute`, while the element it is absolute positioned to is in view, but currently there exists nothing like this nativley, but you could try to recreate it using JS.

Answer (score 1):

### A way to make a sticky element *look* like it's absolutely positioned

I came up with this hack that achieves the goal, but I haven't figured out how to fix its one flaw: There's a blank area at the bottom of the scrollable content equal to the height of the sticky element + its initial vertical offset.

See the comments in the code for an explanation of how it works.

```css
#body {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: Linen;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* to position your sticky element vertically, use the
   height of this empty/invisible block element */
#sticky-y-offset {
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

/* to position your sticky element horizontally, use the
   width of this empty/invisible inline-block element */
#sticky-x-offset {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* this element is sticky so must have a static position,
   but we can fake an absolute position relative to the
   upper left of its container by resizing the invisible
   blocks above and to the left of it. */
#sticky-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
  position: sticky;
  top: -80px;
  bottom: -80px;
}

/* this div will contain the non-sticky main content of
   the container. We translate it vertically upward by
   sticky-y-offset's height + sticky-item's height */
#not-sticky {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
  transform: translateY(-200px);
}

.in-flow {
  width: 90%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: green;
  opacity: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="sticky-y-offset"></div>
  <div id="sticky-x-offset"></div>
  <div id="sticky-item">absolute &amp; sticky</div>

  <div id="not-sticky">
    <div class="in-flow">in flow</div>
    <div class="in-flow">in flow</div>
    <div class="in-flow">in flow</div>
    <div class="in-flow">in flow</div>
  </div>
</div>
```