# how to align this div to appear on right most side of webpage?

Tags: html, css

how to align this div to appear on right most side of webpage:

**CSS**

```
    /*---- CROSS BROWSER DROPDOWN MENU ----*/
ul#nav {
    margin: 0 0 0 200px;
}
ul.drop a {
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
ul.drop {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
    float: left;
}
ul.drop li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: default;
    background: #1e7c9a;
}
ul.drop ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 195px;
    background: #555;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
ul.drop ul li {
    float: none;
}
ul.drop ul ul {
    top: -2px;
    left: 100%;
}
ul.drop li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible
}
.style1 {
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<ul class="drop" id="nav" name="nav">
    <li><a href='calls.php' class="style1">View Trends</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li><a href='calls1.php?id= $date;&id1= $d; ' class="style1">View Trends</a></li>-->
    <li><span class="style1">Run Decision Support System</span>

        <ul>
            <li><span class="style1"><a href="calls.php">Churn Prediction</a></li></span>

                <li><span class="style1"><a href="calls.php">Customers Segmentization</a></li></span>

        </ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="style1">Run Expert System</a> 
        </li>
```

i want to include this navigation bar on my every web page but want this to appear on right side of page... any idea how to do it?

Comment: Take a look at [this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236151/how-to-make-a-div-always-float-on-the-screen-in-top-right-corner)

Comment: you should also take a look at your html formatting, you open tags in a way and close with a different order, <li><span><a> </a></li></span> . nowadays browsers are smart and error forgiving but writing code under w3c rules it's always a good choice. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: use a jsfiddle to quickly format your code and detect syntax errors. it also helps other to figure out quickly how it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/FUKpU/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VWtLT/2/) here http://jsfiddle.net/VWtLT/2/. Done the following chagnes in your css.

```
ul#nav {/*margin: 0 0 0 200px;*/}
ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: right; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just Update the class as I mention below

> ```
> ul.drop {
>     float: right;
>      position: relative;
>      z-index: 597;
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just change float of div to `right` as show below

> ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: right; }

Answer (score 0):

Wow your formatting is extremely messy, I'd recommend hitting return after each line. But based on your title I think the solution is by setting the float to right:

```
#id
{
 float:right;
}
```