# How to make a sticky div with a stopper

Tags: html

someone can tell me how this effect is called when I go down on a web page and there is a box that at first was in the middle of the page but on the way down is stuck to the side of the content and also follow you to the bottom the page. i see this on facebook and many website. I know not a 'Div' because these remain fixed

Sorry I forget to wrote they move when only the top of page touches them

Comment: divs can remain fixed, follow you, move around, disapear, I would say probably you can do it with a div

Comment: Most of the examples you see on the web is achieved with some javascript.

Comment: I think the question is about a div that would start mid way, but when you scroll it moves to the top, but once it hits the top, it stops scrolling, and stays at the top.

Comment: Yes nycynik that is what i want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, you want something to follow you as your scroll down but at first it was in the middle of the webpage. You can make it with some jquery:

[Example](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/sf-example-3.html)

[tutorial](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/)

Comment: Yes! This is what i want but it can be made to responde quicker?

Comment: the plug in i linked to is just one of many - im sure it has parameters to specify MARGIN, PADDING, SPEED etc... so YES you can but you have to go through the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript, you could put a listener on the window for scroll event and calculate distance from end of the div with pageYOffset or similar and then apply css to make that div fixed when the scroll bar reaches that position.

EDIT

Just for the fun, with jQuery;

```
var position = window.pageYOffset;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    position = window.pageYOffset;
    if(position > 150) {
        $('#div').css({ 'top': position + 'px' });
    } 
});
```

and in the CSS;

```
#div {
    position:absolute;
    top: 150px;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that I found that tells you how to do exactly that.

Here is an similar question:
[How do I get a floating footer to stick to the bottom of the viewport in IE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146659/how-do-i-get-a-floating-footer-to-stick-to-the-bottom-of-the-viewport-in-ie-6)

and a tutorial that explains it using jquery.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to reproduce that is by using a div with `position: fixed;` - it will stick to its original position all the way up or down the page.

So, if you have a `div` with your menu:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link1.htm">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.htm">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.htm">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can customize it with

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use some basic css:

```
#fixed {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:150px;
}
```

Comment: You can ommit the "px" when the actual number is 0 :-)